# Assistance with an SQL function

Tags: sql, function, join

This past week I was given an SQL lab involving functions. My knowledge of SQL pre-dating this lab was minimal at best and am having a hard time getting my head around a particular function.

Four tables:

[image]

I am to create a stored function called teamsize which returns the number of players in a given teams name for a particular year. The team name is to be supplied as a parameter passed to the function. To my knowledge a join is required but that is about all I know.

What have I tried:

[image]

Any help is appreciated

Comment: its called a stored procedure usually....Let's see some attempt.

Comment: +1 for well constructed question and pics. -1 for not enough personal effort. Your assignment is probably to create a [stored procedure](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38682/Overview-of-SQL-Server-Stored-Procedure), not a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give it a try.
Your main table would be Team, so you have to

```
select 
from team 
where Team1.teamID = your_parameter and Team1.year = your_year
```

Since you don't need details about the players, just amount, you can just join the Team1 table with playerTeam1 and count the number of records with a count function.

If you needed the player's details, you would need to join the other tables, but since it isn't necessary you are fine with the only 2 tables I mentioned.

Comment: I have posted a screenshot I have tried so far above